# Transferring CSV/Excel doc to a client server R

Tags: r, json, csv, dataframe, shiny

A client server will be hosting my R code for a webApp. I need to transfer data frames so when the server runs the R code it also loads my data frames into it's environment. Is this possible?

Comment: Assuming the right parameters are provided (e.g. `colClasses`), `write.csv()` and then `read.csv()` should suffice, at least from what it sounds. Alternatively, `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()` (saving/loading an R object) would be another option.

Comment: Or ?save(), ?load() for multiple dataframes.

Comment: Thanks guys. The save(), function is just what I am looking for